# mlr: Extract penalized logistic regression coefficients

Tags: r, coefficients, mlr

When using `mlr`, the parameters of the fitted model are (according to the documentation https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/train/index.html) accessed with `getLearnerModel()`. However, with penalized logistic regression, this just tells me the number of coefficients, but not what they are. How do I get the coefficient values? Here's an example of where I fail to get the values with `getLearnerModel()`.

```r
library(mlr); library(titanic); suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
#> Loading required package: ParamHelpers
data("titanic_train")
data <- titanic_train %>% 
  transmute(age = Age,
            class = as.factor(Pclass),
            survived = as.factor(Survived)) %>% 
  drop_na()
glimpse(data)
#> Observations: 714
#> Variables: 3
#> $ age      <dbl> 22, 38, 26, 35, 35, 54, 2, 27, 14, 4, 58, 20, 39, 14,...
#> $ class    <fct> 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2,...
#> $ survived <fct> 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,...
task <- makeClassifTask(data = data, target = "survived")
learner <- makePreprocWrapperCaret("classif.penalized")
#> Loading required package: penalized
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Welcome to penalized. For extended examples, see vignette("penalized").
model <- train(learner, task)
getLearnerModel(model)
#> Model for learner.id=classif.penalized; learner.class=classif.penalized
#> Trained on: task.id = data; obs = 714; features = 2
#> Hyperparameters: trace=FALSE
```

Created on 2018-04-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Have you tried `getLearnerModel(model)@weights`?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to work when `makePreprocWrapperCaret()` is used.

Comment: Oops, I meant `getLearnerModel(model)$learner.model@weights`.

Comment: `getLearnerModel(model)$learner.model@weights` gets something other than the coefficients. Comparing it to @Michel's answer below, there are differences.

Comment: Yes, it gives something very different, sorry, I was completely wrong

Comment: Just for the sake of exploring the object `getLearnerModel(model)`, I found the coefficients in `getLearnerModel(model)$learner.model@penalized`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a wrapped learner. To retrieve the base learner of a (multiply) nested learner, use `getLearnerModel(model, more.unwrap = TRUE)`. For your example

```
coef(getLearnerModel(model, more.unwrap = TRUE))
```

should work.